# Can't concentrate during salaah while standing

Tags: salat, masjid, imaan

My achilles tendon is short so i can't stand on my heels, only on my foot. The problem is that it is very hard for me to maintain my balance like that and and because of it it is very hard for me to concentrate. What can i do?

Comment: You can pray by seating, or manage a chair to sit.

Answer (score 1):

You can pray while sitting, either on the ground or on a chair. A lot of people I know have arthritis and pray on a chair.

> Pray while standing and if you can't, pray while sitting and if you
>   cannot do even that, then pray Lying on your side. ([al-bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/18/37))

Answer (score 0):

All prayers are depends on your intentions. Islam is that religion where you never face hurdle in worship of Allah. You can pray according to that method which you feel relaxed and if you can’t stand you sit on chair and if you can’t sit than you follow that method which is easy.

Comment: Evidences would make this answer more profitable, see [answer].